# How to change the format of the date Calendar Control vs2010 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime, date, calendar, date-format

I am trying to store DoteOfBirth from a Calender control in visual studio 2010.

```
      Dim dob As Date = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

I wanna save like **dd/MM/yyyy** without anything else but when i save it it shows like

```
      2012-02-28T00:00:00+00:00
```

I don't know where to change the format and I don't know how to remove the thing attached to the date. I am writing it in vb.net and saving to xml file.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a `DateTimePicker` control, you should use the `Format` or `CustomFormat` properties.

If you're using the `MonthCalendar` control ... well, you may consider using the `DateTimePicker` instead, as per this excerpt from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.aspx):

> If you need custom date formatting and a selection limited to just one date, you might consider using a DateTimePicker control instead of a MonthCalendar. Using the DateTimePicker eliminates much of the need for validating date/time values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Liquid .. i found out that, I got that long date because of the column type (date) in the datatable, rather than the setting on the calendar control. If I change the column type to String, i got the date as I wanted but i am not sure it is a good idea to have date as a string. thanks anyway.

Comment: @LaurenceNyein:  That's not a good idea.  You should *always* store dates in a column with a data type of DateTime (or Date in Sql 2008).  You should only ever change the format when *displaying* the date.